# PHP glob range small issue why?

Tags: php

I have a small issue for displaying photos by range from a folder.

My current PHP code :

```
$start = 0007;
$end = 0015;

$filenames = glob("$dirname/*{" . implode(",", range($start, $end)) . "}*", GLOB_BRACE);
            foreach ($filenames as $filename)
            {
                $tempo=explode('/',$filename);

                echo "<div class=\"col-lg-3 col-md4 col-xs-6 thumb\">";
                echo "<a class=\"thumbnail\" href=\"$softname?photo:$tour:$ordre:::$tempo[4]:$clients_id::::$argconcours\">";
                echo "<p align=\"center\">$tempo[3]/$tempo[4]</p>";
                echo "<img class=\"img-responsive\" src=\"$filename\" alt=\"$filename\">";
                echo "</a>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
```

It displays photos 0008.jpg, 0018.jpg 0028.jpg ... 0080.jpg 0009.jpg, 0019.jpg ... 0089.jpg, 0011.jpg, 0012.jpg, 0013.jpg, 0014.jpg, 0015.jpg,

Looks like it display all photos where it finds the number 8 or 9 then do 11,12,13,14,15. I don't see what i'm doing wrong for it displays only from 0007 to 0015.
Exemple of photo name : W32_0008.JPG

Comment: Take a look at what you get with "range", this is the output: /*{7,8,9,10,11,12,13}* ... you a different approach to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add an "end" to your expression, so you can realize the "range" feature: (example with only searching .jpg)

```
glob("$dirname/*0{" . implode(",", range($start, $end)) . "}.jpg", GLOB_BRACE);
```

this will only find files, when there is a leading zero in the range!

Comment: Tested it, it returns just 0015.JPG and if I replace the comma next to the implode inside double quotes by two dots like suggested by Mark Baker it display nothing.

Comment: Made an edit, had a typo in it. Place the .jpg outside the brakets, this works at my maschine.

Comment: I now tested it with your edit and it displays lot of photos 0007.JPG, 0017.JPG, 0027.JPG...

Comment: question: is there always a 0 in front the range?

Comment: Yes because all photos will have 4 digits like W20_1382.JPG or W21_0001.JPG. I've posted an answer that solve my issue but it might be dirty code

Comment: so if there is always a 0 leading, i have edited my post for this special reason

Comment: That is working perfectly ! I guess it's also way better than my posted answer with the loop. Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

Numeric values that start with a `0` like `0007` and `0015` are treated as **octal** numbers.

`0007` (octal `7`) will equate to decimal `7`

but `0015` (octal `15`) will equate to decimal `13`

I'd imagine that your problem won't be an issue if you define these as **string** values:

```
$start = '0007';
$end = '0015';
```

**EDIT**

I'd also suspect that you should be using the `..` range operator in your glob expression rather than a comma separated list of numbers (assuming PHP's glob wrapper supports all features of glob)

```
glob("$dirname/*{" . $start . '..' . $end . "}.jpg", GLOB_BRACE);
```

Comment: Oh octals values good to know it. I've put $start and $end into string like you are showing but the result is the same. I tested with double quote too but no changes sadly.

Comment: I tested my initial glob with .. instead of a comma then yours, both returns no photos. Could it be a feature not supported? Your glob with a single comma returns only 0007.jpg and 0015.jpg

Comment: My glob doesn't have any comma (`,`) it has two dots (`..`) which is the __glob range operator__

Comment: Yes, I've writed the two dots like you writed in your answer and it returns no photos. Do you think it would be not supported ?

Answer (score 0):

I had an idea of PHP code and it seems to have solved my problem. I think it might be a dirty code. I'm open for advice or better way to do it.

```
while ($start <= $end) {
            $start = sprintf('%04d', $start);
            $end = sprintf('%04d', $end);

            $filenames = glob("$dirname/*" . $start . ".JPG", GLOB_NOSORT);
            foreach ($filenames as $filename)
            {
                $tempo=explode('/',$filename);

                echo "<div class=\"col-lg-3 col-md4 col-xs-6 thumb\">";
                echo "<a class=\"thumbnail\" href=\"$softname?photo:$tour:$ordre:::$tempo[4]:$clients_id::::$argconcours\">";
                echo "<p align=\"center\">$tempo[3]/$tempo[4]</p>";
                echo "<img class=\"img-responsive\" src=\"$filename\" alt=\"$filename\">";
                echo "</a>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
            $start++;   
        }
```