# php glob number range in filename

Tags: php, glob

I've checked two other answers but can't seem to match a range of numbers in file name

I need to match 1.jpg to anything upto 99.jpg (no leading zeros and no prefix or suffix), just plain digits.jpg

```
glob("$dir/{1..99}.jpg", GLOB_BRACE);
```

and I've also tried:

```
glob("$dir/{" . implode(",", range(1, 99)) . "}.jpg", GLOB_BRACE);
```

The following matches only 1.jpg to 9.jpg but not 10,11 etc

```
glob("$dir/[0-9].jpg", GLOB_BRACE);
```

The following matches nothing:

```
glob("$dir/[0-9]+.jpg", GLOB_BRACE);
```

I've already checked solutions in [PHP glob range small issue why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628429/php-glob-range-small-issue-why) and [php glob pattern match for arbitray number of digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506491/php-glob-pattern-match-for-arbitray-number-of-digits)

Comment: `glob("$dir/[0-99].jpg", GLOB_BRACE);`

Comment: and what about something like `[0-9][0-9]+.jpg`? (*my regex is quite rusty*) You need to add another condition. Then that answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33628481/ that's in one of those links `glob("$dirname/*{" . $start . '..' . $end . "}.jpg", GLOB_BRACE);` why wouldn't that work? or `glob("$dirname/*0{" . implode(",", range($start, $end)) . "}.jpg", GLOB_BRACE);` I can't see how that would fail.

Comment: @Mihai `[0-99]` didn't work

Comment: @Fred-ii- `[0-9][0-9]+` returns 0 results.. and I have no idea why it's not working. I will do more tests tomorrow as I'm shattered now

Comment: @Onimusha Glad to see you found your solution.

Comment: @Onimusha Why would you expect that to work? `+` is a regular expression operator, it has nothing to do with glob patterns.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm surprised that you don't know the difference between regexp and glob.

Comment: @Barmar just goes to show how little I know.

Comment: @Barmar no one was expecting `[0-9]+` to work. The expectation from Fred-ii was on the range code. `Read` and understand before playing Einstein :)

Comment: @Onimusha I thought that was what you were referring to when you said " I have no idea why it's not working". I'm also unsure why the `range()` code didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
glob("$dir/{,[1-9]}[0-9].jpg", GLOB_BRACE);
```

The `GLOB_BRACE` option tells it to recognize alternatives in braces, so `{,[1-9]}` matches either an empty string or a non-zero digit. Then this is followed by any digit. So with the empty string it matches `0` through `9`, and with the non-zero digit it matches `10` through `99`.

Comment: One of the best answers Sir :-)

Comment: Perfect.. instantly found 1,2,3,4 and 12.jpg... Thanks a lot